# Show different model admin list_display and fields set for different user groups

Tags: django, field, admin, editing

In django I have superuser and group of content editors.

When I edit model as superuser I want be able to edit all fields. And if someone logged in as editor I want to allow him to edit only specific fields.

I have done that with `get_form` method:

```
class VideoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    editor_fields = ('description','description_rewrited')

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(request.user, 'perms_list'):
            request.user.perms_list = request.user.groups.values_list('name',flat=True)

        if 'video_description_rewriter' in request.user.perms_list:
            print('rewrite fields to normal')
            self.fields = self.normaluser_fields

        return super(VideoAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

It works for me. But when I open video for editing as regular editor it changes superuser fields set to editors fields set.

1. Open admin model as superuser - http://joxi.ru/zAN5wWMIVjz429
2. Open admin model as editor - http://joxi.ru/p27LJPZiDNgeA7
3. Now superuser has the same fields set as editor - http://joxi.ru/L21jko5TW0ydAX

I assume that there is some kind of template caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `self.fields` to `self.normaluser_fields` when user is editor, but you aren't setting `self.fields` back to default value when user is admin. `ModelAdmin` objects are created on application load and they're shared between all users!

Changing fields back to default value when admin enters page won't solve problem in 100% percent. When admin and non-admin user will try to enter edit page in same time, race condition might occur. Both of them can get same fields.

Instead of rewritting `get_form`, you can do it simpler by rewritting `get_fields` method:

```
    def get_fields(self, request):
        if not hasattr(request.user, 'perms_list'):
            request.user.perms_list = request.user.groups.values_list('name',flat=True)

        if 'video_description_rewriter' in request.user.perms_list:
            print('rewrite fields to normal')
            return self.normaluser_fields

        return self.fields
```

That method won't overwrite any values in `ModelAdmin` object, so change will be only visible for one user.